# Can snakes suck venom from our body?

Tags: belief, tradition, superstitions

- In many local temples it is claimed that snakes can suck venom from  our body.
- In one Mahabharata episode too it was shown that Bhima was given poisoned food and was thrown into a lake and a snake sucked the poison from his body.

Comment: But imagine what will happen if , while sucking, it injects some its own venom into our body? :)  It must be a divine snake or a specially trained one!

Comment: In case of Bheema, Snakes never suck venom from his body. Actually they did byte him. As we all know poison kills poison, so because of their byte, the effect of poison in his body got over. Snakes were actually trying to kill him but since a different poison already was present in his body, so poison of snakes did positive effect for him instead of negative. Their poison turned out like medicine for him just because a different poison already present in his body which was given by Korwas.

Comment: yes, but it has to bite you in the exact same place as you were bitten!!

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda friend can you give scriptures in the answer area